# Using jQuery to animate a hover effect for IE9, works fine on mouseover but when you leave it it acts weird

Tags: jquery, css

I have a quote box on my website that sits off to the right of the browser. On hover it displays a list of available dates. I tried using css transition which worked fine on all browsers except IE, surprise surprise. So I turned to jQuery. I came up with this:

```
<div id="quote">
    <p>Quote</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
#quote {
background: #9C1818;
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
border-radius: 10px;
margin-right: -100px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 60px!important;
-ms-transform:rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Opera */
}

#quote:hover {
    transform:rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Safari */
    -ms-transform:rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
     -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Firefox */
     -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Opera */
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#quote').css({
    backgroundPosition: "0 0"
}).hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
          height: '150px',
  width: '250px',
        backgroundPosition: "(200px 0px)"
    }, {
        duration: 900
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
          height: '150px',
  width: '150px',
        backgroundPosition: "(0px 200px)"
    }, {
        duration: 900
    });
});
```

This works how I want it on mouseover but when I leave it it jumps the height of the box way up to what the width is, I know why it's doing this, because of the transforms, but I need the word 'quote' to act like that. I'm new at jQuery so I'm not sure if there's an easier way of accomplishing this. Basically the functionality I want is for the box to move to the left on hover, and then move back to the right when left with no difference in height.
Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mandykiwi/jJqGu/)

/***EDIT***/
I found a solution, I put the hover transform on the p like so:

```
#quote p {
    -ms-transform:rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Opera */
}

#quote:hover p {
     transform:rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Safari */
    -ms-transform:rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
     -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Firefox */
     -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Opera */
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way but it works for me

Comment: `transition` works fine in IE10. People shouldn't be using IE9 because of Windows Update ;) So it's their own fault if they don't see your transitions.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but unfortunately I have to make IE8+ work with it :P

Comment: No, I'm afraid you're wrong there. You do not "have" to make IE8 work with it. We developers should not have to waste hours of our time just because people can't be bothered to keep their system up to date. Especially with CSS, if it doesn't look as beautiful as it might otherwise do, it's not the end of the world.

Comment: That makes no sense Kolink .. if you have Ecommerce stores and you want a broad range of users to buy from you, you will still debug for IE8 since those users are XP users who cant upgrade. XP will have support dropped in 2014.. so to say you don't have to make it work in IE8 is just wrong and lazy.. especially if you want to still get those users business, despite the fact they don't upgrade their OS, or use a proper broswer like Firefox or Chrome

Comment: also user2596635 you don't need the vendor prefixes for the transform property since they work in the latest Firefox, Chrome, and IE .. http://caniuse.com/#search=transforms

Comment: @user2596635 If you have solved your own issue, you should post this as an answer and accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Tried to, I guess I have to wait a few hours before doing so

Answer (score 0):

try this to get the rotate to work in ie8:

```
#quote {
    background: #9C1818;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: -100px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 60px!important;

    /* Modern Browsers */
    transform:rotate(270deg); 

    /* transform for IE */
    /* IE8 */   
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=-0.00000000, M12=1.00000000, M21=-1.00000000, M22=-0.00000000,sizingMethod='auto expand')";
    /* IE6,IE7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=-0.00000000, M12=1.00000000, M21=-1.00000000, M22=-0.00000000,sizingMethod='auto expand');

}
```

use the **IE filter** to apply rotation.. as you can see IE has supported this filter for rotation even as early as IE6

also above you forgot to add the **transform** without the prefix for modern browsers.. you don't need the vendor prefix for the **transform** property anymore

http://caniuse.com/#search=transforms

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

[SHOW DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IFozabU/2/edit)

I separated the `#quote` style from `p`...

CSS:

```
#quote { 
   height: 150px;
   width: 150px;
   padding: 20px 0;
   border-radius: 10px;
   margin-right: -100px;
   background: #9C1818;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 60px!important;  
}

#quote p {
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   margin: 0 0 0 10px;
   -ms-transform:rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
   -moz-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Firefox */
   -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
   -o-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Opera */
}
```